# Invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, char, string-literals

A simple C++ code:

```
int main(){
unsigned char* t="123";
}
```

on compilation with g++ gives following error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘unsigned char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Why?

Comment: Because a string literal is const.

Comment: Thanks. So how to resolve it? Apart from using std::string

Comment: And yes, if it is string literal, gcc does not give error on that.

Comment: If you mean that using a C compiler doesn't give an error, that's (partially) because in C , `"123"` has type `char[4]` whereas in C++ it has type `const char[4]`.  gcc , if not invoked in standard mode, also allows conversion between `char *` and `unsigned char *` without a cast

Comment: `const unsigned char* tmp= reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( "123" ); t = const_cast<unsigned char *>(tmp)`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. For example string literal `"123"` has type `const char[4]`.

In expressions with rare exceptions arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in this declaration

```
unsigned char* t="123";
```

the initializer has type `const char *`. There is no implicit conversion from `const char *` to `unsigned char *`

You could write

```
const unsigned char* t = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( "123" );
```

Comment: Thanks gcc handles it in a different way then.

Comment: @anupamD It is better to follow the standard instead of using language extensions of the compiler.:)

Comment: The initializer has type `const char[4]`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, which gets you a modifiable `unsigned char` array as you originally wanted, is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    unsigned char ta[] = "123";
    unsigned char* t = ta;

    cout << t << endl;  // Or ta.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can add `const` to both declarations if you wish, to get `const unsigned char` without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

1. just char* in place of unsigned char* during declaration
2. char t[MAX_SIZE] = "123"; // MAX_SIZE should be defined earlier
3. time tested *strcpy()* and *strncpy* functions

Answer (score 0):

Conversions from one type to another type is easy when you use self-defined macros. So here is a set of macros you can use across any platform (Windows, Linux, Solaris, AIX etc...)

```
#define M_ToCharPtr(p)        reinterpret_cast<char*>(p)                   // Cast to char*
#define M_ToWCharPtr(p)       reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(p)                // Cast to wchar_t*
#define M_ToConstCharPtr(p)   reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p)             // Cast to const char*
#define M_ToConstWCharPtr(p)  reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(p)          // Cast to const wchar_t*
#define M_ToUCharPtr(p)       reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p)          // Cast to unsigned char*
#define M_ToConstUCharPtr(p)  reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(p)    // Cast to const unsigned char*
#define M_ToUCharPtr(n)       reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(n)          // Cast to unsigned char*
#define M_ToVoidPtr(p)        reinterpret_cast<void*>(p)                   // Cast to void*
#define M_ToConstVoidPtr(p)   reinterpret_cast<const void*>(p)             // Cast to const void*
#define M_ToIntPtr(n)         reinterpret_cast<int*>(n)                    // Cast to int*
#define M_ToConstIntPtr(p)    reinterpret_cast<const int*>(p)              // Cast to const int*
#define M_ToDoublePtr(n)      reinterpret_cast<double*>(n)                 // Cast to double*
#define M_ToConstDoublePtr(n) reinterpret_cast<const double*>(n)           // Cast to const double*
#define M_ToBoolPtr(n)        reinterpret_cast<bool*>(n)                   // Cast to bool*
#define M_ToConstBoolPtr(n)   reinterpret_cast<const bool*>(n)             // Cast to const bool*

// General Cast
#define M_To(T, p)            reinterpret_cast<T>(p)                       // Cast to T
```

**In your case**

```
const unsigned char* t = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>("UCHAR TO CONST UCHAR");
```

is equivalent to

```
const unsigned char* t = M_ToConstUCharPtr("UCHAR TO CONST UCHAR");
```

Comment: These macros are not much shorter and only obfuscate the code.

Comment: Why down vote? If it's wrong then it's acceptable but I'm trying to help coders who want to use macros in conversions. It's not a must to use macros, instead anyone can use the long literals...